# What permissions are required to query master..syslogins in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have readonly access to the master database however the following query only returns a subset of users.  What permissions are needed to return the rest of the users?

```
SELECT [name] FROM master.dbo.syslogins
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of SQL Server are you on??

The `syslogins` catalog view has been deprecated with SQL Server 2005 - if you're on 2005 or up, you should use `sys.server_principals` and `sys.sql_logins` instead.

When you check the [MSDN Books Online topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx) for sys.server_principals, you'll see a note at the bottom of the page:

> In SQL Server 2005 and later versions,
>   the visibility of the metadata in
>   catalog views is limited to securables
>   that a user either owns or on which
>   the user has been granted some
>   permission. For more information, see
>   Metadata Visibility Configuration.

Go to the [Metadata Visibility Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx) page to read up on the details of what objects you will be able to see, and how to get access to others.

This note is the most important part if you want to grant permissions:

> To allow callers to view metadata, you
>   can grant the callers `VIEW
>   DEFINITION` permission at an
>   appropriate scope: object level,
>   database level or server level.
>   Therefore, in the previous example, if
>   the caller has `VIEW DEFINITION`
>   permission on myTable, the stored
>   procedure returns a row.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to "[MetaData Visibilty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx)"

In this case, you'll only see the rows associated with you (groups you are a member of for example).

And it's also [sys.server_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx) now. syslogins is a <strike>ancient relic</strike> legacy view to SQL Server 7 and earlier (was sysxlogins in SQL Server 2000)

From MSDN for sys.server_principals...

> In SQL Server 2005 and later versions,
>   the visibility of the metadata in
>   catalog views is limited to securables
>   that a user either owns or on which
>   the user has been granted some
>   permission. For more information, see
>   Metadata Visibility Configuration.

To see all rows you'll need to [GRANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx) rights.

```
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO ...
```

or

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN::xxx TO ...
```

Or be a "sysadmin"...

Comment: Should be GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO ... (not DEFINITIONS)