# SYSLOGIN not returning all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permissions

I have a situtation, where some login users have incorrect permission somewhere, i.e. 2 queries:

```
--correct, return all rows
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'USER1'
GO
SELECT * FROM syslogins
GO
REVERT
GO

--incorrect, return only 2 rows
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'USER2'
GO
SELECT * FROM syslogins
GO
REVERT
GO
```

Overall both users are mostly identical from what I could find. Where to find what permission is different, and how to fix, so that USER2 could view all rows in syslogins as well?.

From [Metadata Visibility Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration?view=sql-server-2017) tried following query, which didnt return any result.

```
SELECT name, object_id  
FROM sys.tables  
WHERE name = 'syslogins';  
GO
```

From [sys.server_principals (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  tried using following query instead of `SELECT * FROM syslogins` but USER1 still had way more results available as USER2

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.server_principals AS pr   
JOIN sys.server_permissions AS pe ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id
```

Also `grant view definition to USER2` didn't make any changes in thous queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What permissions are required to query master..syslogins in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164185/what-permissions-are-required-to-query-master-syslogins-in-sql-server)

Comment: @DaveBrown While that question address similar situation, it does not really answer my question (at least from what i tried from the given answers)

Comment: Are the users in the same Server Roles? I know sysadmin and securityadmin will return all rows from syslogins and there will be individual permissions that may give similar results (CONTROL SERVER being the one that springs to mind). I'll have a quick play with permissions to see if something comes up.

Comment: from sample query in [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-role-members-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) USER1 have single row (name:DX_USERACCESS) result while USER2 have none. At last found some difference

Comment: OK. Sysadmin and SecurityAdmin server roles will show all logins. Also GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO <user> will show all roles. View Server State, View Any Database and Alter Any Database do NOT show all roles.

Comment: `GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO USER2` fixed the issue, thanks

Comment: As each user, run `select * from sys.login_token;`. Do you see any differences?